# Among `dctor,copy ctor and copy assignment operator`, why deletes one and leaves the other to be implicitly-defined will most likely result in errors

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

As per the documentation(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), which says:

> Classes that manage non-copyable resources through copyable handles
>   may have to declare copy assignment and copy constructor private and
>   not provide their definitions or define them as deleted. This is
>   another application of the rule of three: deleting one and leaving the
>   other to be implicitly-defined will most likely result in errors.

As the subject, i wonder why it occurs.Could sombody explain it in more detail?
Could somebody make it clear by giving some simple example?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the previous paragraph:

> The implicitly-defined special member functions are typically incorrect if the class is managing a resource whose handle is an object of non-class type (raw pointer, POSIX file descriptor, etc), whose destructor does nothing and copy constructor/assignment operator performs a "shallow copy" (copy the value of the handle, without duplicating the underlying resource).

What the rule of three tells you is that you want all your special members (copy constructor, copy assignment operator, and destructor) to be defined the same way: implicitly, explicitly, or not at all.

A class that manages a non-copyable resource is usually a class that owns some hard-to-copy resource. An example is [`std::filebuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf), that manages a file (it's used by `std::fstream`). It does not define a copy constructor nor a copy assignment operator: both are deleted. It does explicitly define a destructor in order to close the file.

Now, if the destructor was left implicitly-defined, the file would never be closed and the buffer would stay in memory, causing a memory leak. If either the copy constructor of the copy assignment operator was implicitly-defined, it would copy the pointer to the buffer, and then the destructor would potentially be called multiple times for the same file, attempting to delete the same buffer multiple times (which is undefined behavior).